# Do we need transit visa through China?

Tags: transit-visas, china, russian-citizens

We are going to fly  this May to Russia From Canada,  Russian citizens.  We have 2 stops in China, Beijing and Harbin, on the way ther spend 14 hours in China, on way back 26 hours. From Harbin to Russia we have different travel providor. Do we need  transit visas  on our way there or back? now since 2019 you have to give your fingerprints taken in Toronto. Is this really needed for transiting through China? 
Could  somebody give me the phone number in China with service in English, so I can hear the answer? so far as I called nobody spoke English

Comment: Why would you expect there to be an English language help line in China?

Comment: @Traveller English is the most widely spoken language in the world (including all speakers, not just native speakers). It wouldn't be at all surprising if English-language help was available.

Comment: @David Richerby It’s actually second, after Mandarin Chinese :-)

Comment: @Traveller Not according to the [statistics Wikipedia quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers).

Comment: @Traveller I believe the difference between you and David Richerby is over first-language speakers and total speakers. I believe the number of people who speak English as their nth language (where n>1) is much greater than that statistic for Mandarin Chinese.